# How can I convert an unknown date stamp to a DateTime object?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have some files that were named by an unknown system, which include a date/time stamp in them. I'd like to convert the date/time stamp to an actual readable string.  Here's some examples:

- 20171104_406014993266 = 2017 11 03 10:27 PM
- 20171030_405900398402 = 2017 10 29 8:23 PM

Currently I'm creating a DateTime object using the first part of the string, like this...

```
System.DateTime.TryParseExact("20171104", "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal,  out date)
```

Then if I subtract ticks like this...

```
System.DateTime time = date.AddTicks(-406014993266);
```

It gets close.

- 20171104_406014993266 = 2017 11 03 12:43:18 PM

How can I determine how this date/time stamp was created, and convert it backj to a DateTime object?

Comment: If you don't know the format of the string then how do you know `20171104_406014993266 = 2017 11 03 10:27 PM` ?

Comment: So where does this difference come from? Maybe the clock on the system that created the files is incorrect, or maybe the times are in UTC or in a specific time zone. Figuring out that information (and acting on it), sounds better to me than subtracting some arbitrary number of ticks.

Comment: @EpicKip he obviously have the said third party system and know when he saved it and assume the date saved inside the file should plus or less match with when he executed the task that created it.

Comment: @EpicKip Because I know the date and time the file was created.

Comment: @Tester101 If the files from a 3rd party you don't know if the timestamp means date created. It might mean time log added/time error caught. I mean I don't know either but no one can do anything with this question as we're just guessing as its a 3rd party...

Comment: @GolezTrol It's not an arbitrary number of ticks.  The number of ticks comes from the file name.   I know that number represents some part of the date/time stamp, I'm just not sure exactly what it represents.

Comment: @Tester101 `I know that number represents some part of the date/time stamp, I'm just not sure exactly what it represents.` If you don't know what part -> you don't know if it represents anything.

Comment: @EpicKip I guess I'm just trying to figure out if this is some common pattern for date/time stamps, that can be easily recognized by someone.

Comment: @Tester101 I can tell you this isn't a common one :) if you actually have to subtract then someone might not want you to know. Or maybe the time is in utc (and file date created not utc?)

Comment: @Tester101 If you just take the values as ticks there is a 11 seconds difference while the date you provide are couple hours difference. So they are not ticks

Comment: @Franck Any idea if there's a way to convert the last part of the date/time stamp to a valid time value? I'm certain that the number represents the time, I'm just not sure how to convert it to a time.

Comment: @Tester101 it's too small to be ticks and too big to be seconds. Unless if it's  something like ticks elapsed since program started. Then it make sense. if you open software at 10:00:00 and executed the method at 10:00:30 then the values could be ticks of 30 seconds.

Comment: @Tester101 - you've already converted it into a _valid_ time value. What you haven't done is convert it to the time value you expected. This question reads like a puzzle - "how do I manipulate this number in such a way that it spits out the answer I expect"?

Comment: @AdamV That's exactly it.  I'm hoping somebody that knows more about DateTime can come along, and solve the puzzle before I can.